# Not getting expected results from pyparsing on a particular grammar

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a binary wire protocol configuration file that I am trying to parse.  This is used to allow computers on both sides of a low bandwidth link to agree on which bits represent which data in a way that allows users to configure them in the field.

The config file strings look like this:

abc:16 => identifier abc has 16 bits

abc:16 def:12 => identifier abc has 16 bits and identifier def has 12

abc:16:p => identifier abc has 16 bits and a single parity bit

abc:16:ecc => identifier abc has 16 bits and two bits for ecc

I am to the point where I've got a grammar that I THINK should parse this correctly but I'm running into a strange problem: I can only have an identifier without parity or ecc as the last statement on a line.  The grammar SHOULD support having identifiers with or without parity anywhere on the line, but for whatever reason that doesn't happen.

So:
abc:16
by itself is OK since there is nothing after it

abc:16:p def:12
is OK because the abc:16:p has a parity on the end

abc:16 def:12
is NOT OK because the abc:16 doesn't have parity AND it's not at the end, but this should be fine

abc:16 def:12:p
also is NOT OK because the non-parity statement isn't at the end, but this also should be perfectly OK

Here is the program:

```
from pyparsing import *
import re

abbr = Word(alphas, min=3, max=4)
#abbr = abbr.setDebug()

separator = Suppress(Literal(":"))
bits = Word(nums, min=1, max=2)
parity = Or([CaselessLiteral("P"), CaselessLiteral("ECC")])

bits_part = separator + bits
#bits_part = bits_part.setDebug()

parity_part = separator + parity
#parity_part = parity_part.setDebug()

statement = abbr + bits_part + Optional(parity_part)
#statement = statement.setDebug()

statement_list = StringStart() + statement + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(White()) + statement) + Optional(Suppress(White())) + StringEnd()

tests = ( 
    "abc:16",
    "abc:15:p", 
    "abc:15:p def:14:ecc",
    "abc:17:p def:q ghi:21:", #this one should fail since "q" isn't parity and you shouldn't have a trailing colon with no parity after it
    "abc:16:p def:12", #this passes so it's OK to have a trailing statement without parity
    "abc:15 def:12:p", #this fails but shouldn't
    "abc:16:p def:12 pqr:11", #this is also failing because anything but the last statement missing parity causes failure, but I don't think that's the right behavior
)

for t in tests:
    try:
        print t
        print statement_list.parseString(t)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

When I run it without debugging turned on I see the following results.  According to my understand (and the comments above) only the third example should fail since it has the "q" where the "p" for parity should be.  Everything else should pass, but raises an exception for a reason I don't understand.

```
abc:16
['abc', '16']
abc:15:p
['abc', '15', 'P']
abc:15:p def:14:ecc
['abc', '15', 'P', 'def', '14', 'ECC']
abc:17:p def:q ghi:21:
Expected end of text (at char 9), (line:1, col:10)
abc:16:p def:12
['abc', '16', 'P', 'def', '12']
abc:15 def:12:p
Expected end of text (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
abc:16:p def:12 pqr:11
Expected end of text (at char 16), (line:1, col:17)
```

When I turn debugging on (it's all commented out in the above example code) and I just look at the "abc:16 def:12" this is the output:

```
abc:15 def:12:p
Match {W:(abcd...) {Suppress:(":") W:(0123...)} [{Suppress:(":") {'P' ^ 'ECC'}}]} at loc 0(1,1)
Match W:(abcd...) at loc 0(1,1)
Matched W:(abcd...) -> ['abc']
Match {Suppress:(":") W:(0123...)} at loc 3(1,4)
Matched {Suppress:(":") W:(0123...)} -> ['15']
Match {Suppress:(":") {'P' ^ 'ECC'}} at loc 7(1,8)
Exception raised:Expected ":" (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
Matched {W:(abcd...) {Suppress:(":") W:(0123...)} [{Suppress:(":") {'P' ^ 'ECC'}}]} -> ['abc', '15']
Expected end of text (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
```

In my mind that confirms that it's trying to match the parity_part, which obviously isn't there.  But I've got it set so that the parity_part is Optional() so I can't figure out why it's insisting on finding it.

Furthermore there is a whitespace char there (between abc:16 and def:12) which I feel should be triggering it to move on, the way I have specified in the statement_list portion of the grammar.  To that end I have also tacked on a "leaveWhitespace()" call to the exerciser at the end:

```
print statement_list.parseString(t).leaveWhitespace()
```

But that didn't change anything (in that it didn't start parsing the way I would expect) so I don't believe that the problem is that it's missing the whitespace.  I can't discount it entirely of course.

I am getting pretty perplexed here because I've tackled this from every angle that I can think of and I still don't get what I would expect.  Am I specifying the grammar wrong?  Is pyparsing doing something wrong?  I feel pretty confident that I've made the mistake somewhere but I really can't see it.

EDIT:

So Paul has pointed out that I've got a bunch of dumb whitespace stuff everywhere and that when he trashed all that and simplified things worked fine.  The whitespace stuff was there on purpose because I was going to try and prevent people from doing something like:

"abc :   10  :       ecc"

because it looks bad, not because it doesn't contain the right information.

I am not sure that it's worth it to me to prevent people from putting spaces where I think they shouldn't so Paul's answer is probably good enough for me to move on with my life.

But I am still curious why the version I cooked up didn't work and the modifications he made did.  They look functionally equivalent to me.

Comment: If you want to take over the whitespace handling in pyparsing, the first thing you should do is call `ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespace("")`, and this will pretty much disable all implicit whitespace skipping. Then you can just define your parsing expressions, but remember to add `White()` expressions where they can occur. (My original rationale for implicit whitespace-skipping was that I was tired of seeing people implement parsers that forced users to put delimiting spaces between every token, like "if ( a != b ) a += b - a", but also found that people put spaces in places you never expect.

Comment: `expr.leaveWhitespace` does not do what you are assuming. It only inhibits the whitespace skipping that occurs before trying to parse `expr`.

Comment: And please dont use this form `parity = Or([CaselessLiteral("P"), CaselessLiteral("ECC")])` - I find `parity = CaselessLiteral("P") ^ CaselessLiteral("ECC")` much easier to read. And why using Or here? There can be no ambiguity in matching "P" vs. "ECC".  If you were matching P or PUT or PURPLE, then you would maybe want to use Or (or just use MatchFirst using the '|' operator, taking care to test in `PURPLE | PUT | P` order). But you should not have any problems with `parity = CaselessLiteral("P") | CaselessLiteral("ECC")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *do* know that pyparsing will skip over whitespace on its own, yes?

I get this to work by defining statement_list as just plain:

```
statement_list = OneOrMore(statement)
```

To keep the multiple statements from running together, you should use Group:

```
statement_list = OneOrMore(Group(statement))
```

And instead of adding your own StringEnd to force the parser to try to process the full string, use `parseAll=True`:

```
print statement_list.parseString(t, parseAll=True)
```